# Which Distro/Virtual Machine combination is fast and stable?

Tags: virtual-machine, desktop

For numerous good reasons I am willing to switch my Notebook's OS from Windows 7 to Linux very soon. However I am not committed to any distribution in particular yet (I use Debian at the moment).

I will have to work in a corporate Windows-environment so a reliable virtual machine is vital for my daily work. My work includes GPU-intense tasks on the windows system.

I would like to run Windows 7 64 Bit inside a VM on Linux preferrably with gnome desktop. What would be the best choice when it comes to the distribution and the VM application?

Comment: Good question would be why do you switch from Windows. Both systems (Windows, Linux) have their positive and negative sides, and both are dissapointing, both are half-baked. Currently there is also a problem with DM on Linux -- you mentioned Gnome, but I hope you realize in what direction Gnome is going -- for many (including me) in wrong one. (The same applies to KDE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The distribution

Choosing the right distro for yourself is not an easy task but it is even more difficult to give help in this task to someone you don't know - there are simply too many variables involved. Unfortunately even if you ask people that are experienced Linux users, almost everyone will recommend to you the distro he/she uses him/herself - it is too individual.

I believe the best way is to take some online quiz [like this one](http://www.zegeniestudios.net/ldc/index.php?firsttime=true) (or find other for comparison).

Based only on the factors you mentioned (speed, stability, beginner-level) the first thing that comes naturally to my mind is ***"not easy"***. All those factors more or less contradict each other. So you'd need to find a balance - based on what learning curve you are willing to accept and how you prioritize your needs. So just take some quiz(es) or shoot.

#### The VM

At this point, the choice is easier because there are only a few of those. If you want (like I did) a one that is free and easy to use - I'd recommend **VirtualBox**. Reading that you already used it on Windows, I see it is just an obvious choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing it out. I was afraid there wouldn't be a final answer on the distro side of things, so I'll stay with Debian and most likely will use VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Keep using Debian. It's considered to be as stable as Linux-based distributions get, and its development suites (Testing and Unstable) aren't too bad either.

I personally only ever used VirtualBox, and it's quite featureful and easy-to-use, but not exactly as stable as I hoped it would be (maybe because I'm running Unstable :). That it has a snapshot feature makes the complaint almost moot, unless you are going to be running an important server. Perhaps someone else would suggest a superior virtualisation option.

Note that more recent versions (**4.x**) of VirtualBox are available as backports, but I'd recommend you stay with the Stable version (**3.x**) since I've had better stability issues with it.

Comment: I use VirtualBox a lot with Windows as host OS. I never had it running on Debian but I certainly like it for the nice GUI and ease of use, os I might go with this one…

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, what did you meant by "GPU-intense tasks", but if you meant CAD and other 3D apps that require no higher than DirectX 9 or OpenGL 2.1, then the latest VMware (Workstation or Player) could be a reasonable choice. 
Regarding the distribution, OpenSuse is suitable for beginners, features the Gnome desktop that you mentioned, and installing VMware on it is quite easy.

Comment: There is no 3D involved, ist is mostly OpenGL features that will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is very hard to recommend something here. If you feel fine with Debian stay with it. For the right virtualization solution I would recommend KVM because it is well integrated into the kernel and it works in the same way as many other Linux tools. I have no idea how good it is when it comes to GPU related tasks. I'd just try it out.

Please also be aware that stability of an OS depends a lot on the hardware and the drivers for it.

BTW I am using KVM on openSUSE 11.4 without any issues.

Comment: I would not recommend OS 11.4 to anyone -- I am long-time user of OS, but with this version something went terrible wrong, it crashes on copying files on big disks (over 2TB), and mplayer crashes a lot. Both bug reports are still open (meaning the bugs are not fixed): https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=684752 and https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=687894

Comment: Just a wild guess: this sounds like a driver or hardware issue.

Comment: what can I say, I have smile all over my face -- in short you said it was software or hardware issue :-D So your "guess" by definition is correct.